# bootstarp menu: col-md computed hight is 1px despite div not empty

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap theme on my site.

My menu items displays as intended on localhost as shown in the image below:

[col-md-9 on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thcXG.png)

However, on the remote host, the column has only 1px computed height, even though the 'divs' are not empty. I tried clearing caches and re-uploading the code.

[col-md-9 on remove server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DMYG.png)

The computed styles are both the same on localhost and server. I'm running out of ideas how to debug this.

Comment: Does your remote host actually have the menu? It's hard to debug this for you when there is no code added to your question. Edit your question to post the code that's output on your page from your localhost and your remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Add an version at the end of the  "script" and "link"

before: `<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
after:`<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet?ver=20170503001" />`

This way can deal with the caches of css and js files.

2.Add some parameter after your url.

before: `wwww.xxx.com`
after:`www.xxx.com?ver=aaa`

This way can deal with the caches of html files **maybe**